# Getting disc path to a Matrix File without using a tag pair

Tags: ee2, matrix

I'm currently forced to do this to get a disc path that I can send to CE Image for resizing:

```
{exp:ce_img:single src="{product_carousel_images limit='1'}{slide_image}{rel_path}{/slide_image}{/product_carousel_images}" width="320"}
```

I though there was a way to do something like

```
 {exp:ce_img:single src="{product_carousel_images limit='1'}{slide_image:rel_path}{/product_carousel_images}" width="320"}
```

But that does not seem to work. It'd be even better if I could do something this:

```
{exp:ce_img:single src="{product_carousel_images:1:slide_image:rel_path}" width="320"}
```

But that is a different problem.

For various reasons using remote images is not an option for us - we use a BasicAuth on all of our sites during development, and it a hit to performance to load massive images over HTTP then re-cache them, when they can easily be loaded from local disc.

Comment: Hey Isaac, do you mean your server path?  I'd first recommend getting the data out of Matrix before adding CE Image.  One step at a time.  Have you been able to get the path that you need to echo using only Matrix tags?  Let's first get your data echoing then figure out the CE image integration.  Also, I am curious what about the first option (that you said works) is not a good fit for you?